# Textbox not sending entered value to c sharp code

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

When i click the button to update the certain row in the comments_tbl it runs but the data isnt sent and the data in the database table remains the same..

I have the following html in an aspx so it is already in a form:-

```
<p>Comment<asp:TextBox ID="commenttext" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>
```

I have the following button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

and the following code behind the button is as follows:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        myConnection.Open();

        string commenttextupdate = commenttext.Text;
        int row = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["commentID"]);
        string query = null;
        query = "UPDATE comments_tbl SET comment=@comment WHERE ID = @cid";
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", commenttextupdate);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", Request.QueryString["commentID"].ToString());

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
        Response.Redirect("../reports.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Do you get the correct id in `row`? (Which you by the way should use in the parameter instead of getting the string from querystring again and convert it to a string...)

Comment: @IgorSemin: That would work if the form is sent as a GET request, but normally it's a POST.

Comment: @Timmy Lennon : are you try to open connection in page load.

Comment: We'll need some more information; have you tried debugging this in Visual Studio? What does the value of `Request.QueryString["commentID"]` resolve to - are you sure that there is a row in the database with ID matching this value?
Also, why are you converting `Request.QueryString["commentID"]` to an `int` into the `row` variable but not using it in the `SqlCommand` parameters?